# Compilation of Fortan code with f2py creates empty Python module

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

I have a large Fortran 90 code that I would like to compile with `f2py` so I can run it from within a Python code. I do get the compilation to run without any errors, like this:

`f2py -c -lgomp -lcfitsio.10 -L/usr/local/opt/cfitsio/lib/ -m code_name code_name.f90`

Importing of `code_name` into Python works, but the subroutines are not included. It seems to have created an empty Python module.

I think it might be related to how I had set up the Fortran code, which has the following structure:

```
program code_name

implicit none

"many defined variables"

call run

contains

subroutine run

end subroutine run

"many more subroutines"

end program code_name
```

From a terminal, the code would execute the `run` subroutine. I would like to run it in a same way with Python, so calling `code_name.run()`.

Any suggestions on how I could make this work?

Thanks a lot for any help !

Comment: From Python you typically want to run subroutines. But those subroutines should somehow be self-sufficient.  It is not clear what the `"many defined variables"` does and how the subroutine access these variables (or not) and why these variables are there at all. It is not even.clear whether the subroutine isn't actually internal to the program.

Comment: Show us the *actual code*, a [mcve]. How are the variables used? Either 1. Is the subroutine behind `contains`? or 2. Are the variables in a module? or 3. Are the variables in a common block?

Comment: Thanks for your comments! The `"many defined variables"` are globally defined variables that are used by all subroutines. I guess this should be setup differently for it to work if the subroutines are converted into Python modules. Perhaps my actual question is how to handle the `contains`. In the `f2py` examples that I have seen, that fortran statement is not used so I wonder if that causes the subroutines not to be included with the `f2py` compilation.

Comment: The simple answer to how f2py handles `contains` is likely that it doesn't. f2py is about interfacing with Fortran program units that can be called from Python; internal subroutines cannot be called from Python (or anywhere outside the containing Fortran unit unless we account for the horrors of procedure pointers to internal procedure). We need a clear example and a statement of what you want to do, and why, to give specific advice.

Comment: Ok, there is actually `contains` in your code, I missed it in my first read. Your subroutine is an *internal* subroutine. Internal subprograms are not accessible from the outside. You really should show a more specific piece of code but moving the data into a module might help.

Comment: Whatever your question, the answer is likely to involve rewriting your Fortran program. Internal procedures certainly have their places, but facilitating testing and reuse dont feature in their benefits.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! I will try to rewrite things without `contains`. The problem seems indeed that these are internal subroutine, so they are not compiled with `f2py`.